# JFrame not working - content does not appear

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Not sure what my issue is.  I created a `JFrame` and I have a panel that will have 4 large buttons (with graphics - though that isn't coded yet) to show on the frame but I am getting an error when it tries to run this and the panel isn't showing up in the frame.

UPDATED:  No error message, but no panel or buttons in the frame...

```
public class EasyExpress {
private static JFrame frame = new JFrame("EASY BUTTONS");
private JButton WriteBTN = new JButton("Write Email");
private JButton EmailBTN = new JButton("View Emails");
private JButton SolBTN = new JButton("Play Solsuite Solitaire");
private JButton ShutBTN = new JButton("Shutdown Computer");

private JPanel btnPanel;

public EasyExpress() {


    /*  try {
            Image img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("write.jpg"));
            WriteBTN.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));         
          } catch (IOException ex) {
          }*/

    btnPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,4,1,1));
    btnPanel.setBounds(0, 0, 1200, 400);        


    WriteBTN.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,400));
    EmailBTN.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,400));
    SolBTN.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,400));
    ShutBTN.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,400));

    btnPanel.add(EmailBTN);
    btnPanel.add(WriteBTN);
    btnPanel.add(SolBTN);
    btnPanel.add(ShutBTN);


    frame.add(btnPanel);

    frame.add(frame);

}




public static void main(String[] args) {

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);  
    frame.setSize(1200,400);
    frame.setVisible(true);


}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: EasyExpress is already a JFrame. Why are you trying to add another JFrame to it?

Comment: You can't add a JFrame to another JFrame. Start by removing `extends JFrame` it's one source of confusion

Comment: I updated the code, I no longer get an error but the buttons are not showing up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @MadProgrammer mentioned in the comments above, you can't have a JFrame inside another JFrame.

However, instead of removing the `extends JFrame`, I would suggest removing the JFrame inside your EasyExpress object. You already set all the properties for that JFrame in your main, so it will be easier to fix.

1. Remove `JFrame frame = new JFrame("EASY BUTTONS");`
2. Add "EASY BUTTONS" to the EasyExpress object you create in main `EasyExpress main = new EasyExpress("EASY BUTTONS");`
3. Remove frame. from in front of `frame.add(btnPanel);`

Answer (score 2):

Essentially, you're adding a frame to another frame, which you simply can't do

You're also not initialising your buttons, which is causing a `NullPointerException`.

Start by removing `extends JFrame`, this is just confusing things and as general rule, you should avoid extending from top level containers.  Instead, start with a `JPanel`, for example...

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class EasyExpress extends JPanel {

    JButton WriteBTN, EmailBTN, SolBTN, ShutBTN;
    JPanel btnPanel;

    public EasyExpress() {

        btnPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 4, 1, 1));
        btnPanel.setBounds(0, 0, 1200, 400);

        WriteBTN = new JButton("1");
        EmailBTN = new JButton("2");
        SolBTN = new JButton("3");
        ShutBTN = new JButton("4");

        WriteBTN.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 400));
        EmailBTN.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 400));
        SolBTN.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 400));
        ShutBTN.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 400));

        btnPanel.add(EmailBTN);
        btnPanel.add(WriteBTN);
        btnPanel.add(SolBTN);
        btnPanel.add(ShutBTN);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(btnPanel);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new EasyExpress());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```